# Task Scheduler open Excel file with command line flag for VBA

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, vba, cmd.exe, windows-task-scheduler

I want to open a macro enabled workbook to capture data from the user every hour, and also pass an `/e/ScheduledOpen` flag to it to indicate in VBA if it was opened by task scheduler (in which case it will auto-close) or opened manually (in which case it should stay open).

I most care about *UX* and *Portability* - so I don't really want to rely on writing any additional `.vbs` or `.bat` scripts. VBA macros are not locked-down by IT security but those things might be. The users of the file opened by this task are not themselves programmers and may be scared off by command prompts appearing.

In Task scheduler I'm making the task "Run a program or script". I have tried several nearly good things:

- `explorer "C:/path/to/file.xlsm"` is ideal for User Experience and Portability, as it simulates double clicking the file - I don't need to know the path to Excel.exe or worry about existing instances as these are handled gracefully.

  - The issue is  I can't pass the `/e/ScheduledOpen` flag to Excel VBA.
- `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" "C:/path/to/file.xlsm" /e/ScheduledOpen` does allow me to supply the flag to VBA

  - The issue is this path to excel varies on each machine so is not portable
  - Also if the file is already open then Excel pops an error message which isn't nice
- `cmd /c ""%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel.lnk" "C:/path/to/file.xlsm" /e/ScheduledOpen"` does allow me to supply the flag to VBA and has dynamic path to excel

  - The issue is it spawns a cmd window which is bad UX
  - Also has the same issue when Excel has the file open already
- "%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Excel.lnk" "C:/path/to/file.xlsm" /e/ScheduledOpen` without cmd in task scheduler doesn't seem to work

---

*I am setting up the task at "install time" (when the .xlsm workbook is first opened) so I can look up the path to Excel.exe from the registry, but it's less portable if they install a new excel version the task will break. If this can be worked around that would be pretty good.*

Answer (score 0):

For a one-liner, try using `start` to launch whatever instance of excel can be found. Mostly equivalent to using \Start Menu\Programs\Excel.lnk.

```
cmd /c start excel "C:/path/to/file.xlsm" /e/ScheduledOpen
```

This does flash a cmd window, but it won't stay around. The testing I did does not show a pop-up if the file is already open.

---

Or you could have your macro update the Excel path in the scheduled task when it gets run, in case of an excel version upgrade